# PostgreSQL data recovery after migration fail

Tags: postgresql, centos7, postgresql-9.4

My team and I are not professional database administrators and we were trying to copy our database from one machine to another for backup purposes. Unluckily we made a mistake of moving the data directory instead of copying it. Something unexpectedly happened during the process and the data was not moved completely. Right now we're missing data for the past one month and both machines are in the same state i.e the original and the copy don't have data for that past month. Is there any possibility of recovering this lost data, and if yes how do we go about it. PostgreSQL version is 9.4 running on centos 7.

Comment: Well if none of you is PG DBA then it is difficult to help remotely... Those missing data they were all in one table (one partitions) or in more tables? If in more tables were they in some separate tablespace?

Comment: yes they were in more tables

Comment: Did you have any separate xlog / wal / recovery processes in place, you may have a chance to replay transactions ? If not this seems more like a file system issue and a linux sysadmin may be your best bet.

Comment: No, I think sysadmin is the way to go, please shed some light about it